# XCTest Doesn't have ActivitySummaries in TestSummaries

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xctest, xcuitest

I'm New to Running XCTest. After running :
open ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Proj/Logs/Tests/TestSummaries.plist

Question 1 : 
When open TestSummaries.plist i can find my all Tests.can't find ActivitySummaries for the tests whose TestStatus is Success. But for the tests whose TestStatus is Failure have ActivitySummaries. Why this behavior ?

Question 2 : 
-For XCUITests ActivitySummaries is present for all Success and Failure tests . But Not for Pure XCTest (Unit)... Can someone Guide me why XCTest doesn't have ActivitySummaries wherein XCUITests does have the same or Is there a way to enable or add it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve activity summeries for success case by doing the following

1. **Product**
2. **Scheme**
3. **Select the scheme you are working**
4. **Edit scheme**
5. **Test Tab**
6. **uncheck the option delete when each test succeds**